# How to point a drop-down on press of TAB key using JSON schema in reactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tabs, jsonschema

I have created a form elements using JSON schema in reactJs. I am unable to focus the control on drop-down filed, instead it skips to the next field.

```
      export default {
 title: 'Create User',
 schema: {
type: 'object',
required: [
  'FirstName',
  'MobileCode',
  'Status',
],
properties: {
  FirstName: {
    title: 'First Name',
    type: 'string',
    minLength: 3,
    maxLength: 30,
  },
  LastName: {
    title: 'Last Name',
    type: 'string',
    minLength: 1,
    maxLength: 30,
  },
  LoginID: {
    title: 'Login ID',
    type: 'string',
    minLength: 3,
    maxLength: 50,
  },
  MobileCode: {
    title: 'Code',
    type: 'number',
    enum: [91, 1, 33, 49],
    enumNames: ['+ 91', '+ 1', '+ 33', '+ 49'],
  },
  MobileNumber: {
    title: 'Mobile Number',
    type: 'number',
    minLength: 6,
    maxLength: 16,
  },

  EmailID: {
    title: 'Email ID',
    type: 'string',
    minLength: 5,
    maxLength: 50,
  },
},
}, 
formData: {
Products: [],
},
 uiSchema: {
 'ui:order': [
  'FirstName',
  'LastName',
  'LoginID',
  'MobileCode',
  'MobileNumber',
  'EmailID',
  '*',
 ],
 FirstName: {
  'ui:widget': 'CustomTextWidget',
  classNames: 'customwidth_23',
  'ui:options': {
    type: 'text',
    placeholder: 'First Name',
  },
  },
  LastName: {
  'ui:widget': 'CustomTextWidget',
  classNames: 'customwidth_23',
  'ui:options': {
    type: 'text',
    placeholder: 'Last Name',
   },
  },
  LoginID: {
  'ui:widget': 'CustomTextWidget',
  'ui:options': {
    type: 'text',
    placeholder: 'e.g. test@test',
   },
   },
  MobileNumber: {
  'ui:widget': 'CustomTextWidget',
  classNames: 'customwidth_33',
  'ui:options': {
    type: 'number',
    placeholder: 'Mobile number',
  },
  },
  MobileCode: {
  'ui:widget': 'CustomDropdownWidget',
  classNames: 'customwidth_13',
  'ui:options': {
    type: 'number',
    placeholder: 'Mobile number',
  },
  },
```

[image]

I need to focus on each field on keypress of tab. It is skipping the drop-down field.

I tried tab-index which is not displaying the option list.

Thank you in advanced.